# Share button - Can the canonical link be different from the og:url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have a page with several share buttons, each pointing to a different content and should be shared on user's wall.

The problem is that, we wish the `href` generated to always point to:

```
http://example.com
```

We tried to make a `og:url` for Facebook to point to:

```
http://example.com/facebook/articleId
```

But the only way it seems to work, is if, the:

```
http://example.com/facebook/articleId
```

also stays on the shared page.

Any workaround for this?